# windows 7 remaining batch file arguments

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

In windows batch files, I know `%1` is replaced with the first argument, `%2` is replaced with the 2nd argument and `%*` is replaced with all arguments.

Is there a way to get all the arguments after the 1st one? (e.g. arguments 2-N) What about all the arguments after the 2nd one?

The `SHIFT` command doesn't seem to affect `%*`.

Answer (score 5):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
CALL :allafter 3 %*
ECHO args=%args%
GOTO :eof

:allafter
FOR /l %%a IN (1,1,%1) DO SHIFT
(SET args=)
:argloop
shift
IF NOT .%1==. SET args=%args% %1&GOTO argloop
IF DEFINED args SET args=%args:~1%
GOTO :eof
```

to get everything after the 3rd argument to `ARGS`

---

Edit - to take care of space-separated elements which may include commas

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
CALL :allafter 3 %*
ECHO args=%args%
CALL :allafter2 3 %*
ECHO args=%args%
GOTO :eof

:allafter
FOR /l %%a IN (1,1,%1) DO SHIFT
(SET args=)
:argloop
shift
IF NOT .%1==. SET args=%args% %~1&GOTO argloop
IF DEFINED args SET args=%args:~1%
GOTO :EOF

:allafter2
SET /a count=%1
SET args=%*
:arg2loop
SET oldargs=%args%
call SET args=%%args:*%1 =%%
IF "%args%"=="%oldargs%" (call SET args=%%args:*%1,=%%) ELSE (SET /a count-=1)
shift
IF %count% gtr -1 GOTO arg2loop
GOTO :EOF
```

Hmm- spoke too soon. This modified routine should play nicer. The previous version treated what was to be defined as one argument `one,two,three` as three separate arguments when the remove-leading-n was invoked.

Comment: If I call this with arguments `a b c d e,f` then I get `d e f` instead of `d e,f`. Is there a way to fix it so that it allows intra-argument commas?

Comment: @tennenrishin You'd need to enclose a comma-containing argument in `"quotes"`. The result would contain the argument still in quotes. To remove the quotes, change `SET args=%args% %1` to `SET args=%args% %~1`

Comment: Thanks, but in my case the invocation is given and I can't change it. Does this mean it is impossible?

Answer (score 3):

Well, there is a way-ish...

By using the `/n` switch on the `shift` command, you can sort of do something like it. However, it will delete all of the argument and put them into a certain variable (so you can't call `%3` anymore without a `for` loop).

```
@setlocal enableextensions
@echo off
:loop
if "%~2" equ "" goto end
set variable=%variable% %~2
shift /2
goto loop
:end
echo %1
echo %variable%
endlocal
```

To separate the parameters again just do a simple `for` loop (I'm sure you can find documentation on it somewhere).

Comment: +1, though there is no reason to enable delayed expansion since you are not using it.

Comment: @dbenham Funny story about that. I put delayed expansion in instead of extensions and I spent 10 minutes trying to find out why the thing didn't work. I guess I forgot to take it out.

Comment: would you mind updating the script to remove them? this looks the simplest, but I'm not familiar with delayed expansions so I don't know what are the implications of it.

Comment: Sure, I'll also remove the typo I made.

Comment: If I call this with arguments `a b c,d` then I get `b c d` instead of `b c,d`. Is there a way to fix it so that it allows intra-argument commas?

Comment: see my answer (just use `set variable=%%j` instead of `echo %%j` to use it later in the script)

Answer (score 1):

Solution without `shift` & `goto`:

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count=0
for %%i in (%*) do set /a count+=1
set "args="
for /l %%i in (2,1,%count%) do if defined args (call set "args=!args! %%%%i") else call set "args=%%%%i"
echo.%args%
endlocal
```

Comment: No, you cannot access arguments greater than `%9` without using SHIFT, (unless you use `%*` and write your own arg parser)

Comment: Even after what dbenham said, +1 for effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
> type t.bat
@echo off
echo %*
for  /f "tokens=1,*delims= " %%i in ("%*") do echo %%j

> t a b c d e f,g h i
a b c d e f,g h i
b c d e f,g h i

> t a,a b c d e f,g h i
a,a b c d e f,g h i
b c d e f,g h i

>
```